# How to get the last variable name out of my URL and use it in a switch statement?

Tags: php, url, query-string

I'm trying to get the last variable name displayed in my url and use it to determine what's displayed on my page. For example, here's my url:

`http://mysite.php/catalog/?department=123&category=456&sub_category=789`

If the URL is showing a `sub_category` then I want to display everything that would be considered a sub category. But, if the url only displays:

`http://mysite.php/catalog/?department=123&category=456`

Then I want to display content that only pertains to category.

Once I get the last varibale name I'll use a switch statement to display the content. I've been working with this code, but it's only getting the first variable name and not the last?

```
switch(key($_GET))
{
    case 'department':
        print('show department');
        break;
    case 'category':
        print('show category');
        break;
    case 'sub_category':
        print('show sub_category');
        break;
}
```

Maybe this isn't the best approach, and if you have a better way than using a switch statement let me know ;)

Comment: Do you need the last parameter or is it just going to be subcategory if subcategory is defined, otherwise category?

Comment: This is pretty much what I want. If subcategory is not there then display category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not rely on the order of query string parameters. The better approach would be to check for the presence of parameters in a specific order:

```
if (isset($_GET["sub_category"]))
{
    print('show sub_category');
}
elseif (isset($_GET["category"]))
{
    print('show category');
}
elseif (isset($_GET["department"]))
{
    print('show department');
}
else
{
    print('show error');
}
```

Comment: Upvote for solving the problem, not just answering the question.

Comment: Hey Salman, I used this at first but changed it to a switch statement. This appears to be the best approach. Let me play with it.

Comment: Works like a damn champ! Embarrassing how easy it was, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition in your category case like so:

```
case 'category':
  if (isset($_GET['sub_category'])) {
    print('show sub_category');
  }  else {
    print('show category');
  }
  break;
```

Comment: really should use isset to check if a variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `$_SERVER` properly configured, I'd say the best way to do so is:

```
<?php

$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($qs, $data);
$keys = array_keys($data);
$last = count($keys)-1;

echo $keys[$last];
```

Comment: Sure, it just grabs what the web server tells PHP is the query string.